# Invalid Checksum react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am forming react-native app using [@philly25/react-native-paytm](https://github.com/opsway/react-native-paytm)

Checksum generated successfully but I am getting Invalid Checksum error, Here is Here is my params to generate checksum :

```
{
CALLBACK_URL: "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=orderId123"
CHANNEL_ID: "WAP"
CUST_ID: "12345"
EMAIL: "d@gmail.com"
INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID: "Retail"
MID: "Xxxxxx97xxxx4310xxx1"
MOBILE_NO: "9414123456"
ORDER_ID: "orderId123"
TXN_AMOUNT: "150"
WEBSITE: "APPSTAGING"
mode: "Staging"
}
```

And here is my final params :

```
{
CALLBACK_URL: "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=orderId123"
CHANNEL_ID: "WAP"
CHECKSUMHASH: "lMo6BXsnCIiX7fmX0N6ApLBTQrg0BrEx5/CWlc7mS6yoOjHb10sU7O0stsdLuvqLwkEL6ixFKIX6CmcFC+3SszF/gAbGFSYiy3UqbxpMORM="
CUST_ID: "12345"
EMAIL: "d@gmail.com"
INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID: "Retail"
MID: "Xxxxxx97xxxx4310xxx1"
MOBILE_NO: "9414123456"
ORDER_ID: "orderId123"
TXN_AMOUNT: "150"
WEBSITE: "APPSTAGING"
mode: "Staging"
}
```

And here is my response :

```
{
BANKTXNID: ""
CURRENCY: "INR"
MID: "Xxxxxx97xxxx4310xxx1"
ORDERID: "orderId123"
RESPCODE: "330"
RESPMSG: "Invalid checksum"
STATUS: "TXN_FAILURE"
TXNAMOUNT: "150.00"
status: "Success"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

plz take the same params to generate the checksum as process txn